# JavaScript nested try exception

Tags: javascript, exception

I am reading up on JavaScript [exceptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#Nesting_try...catch_Statements):

> You can nest one or more try...catch statements. If an inner
>   try...catch statement does not have a catch block, the enclosing
>   try...catch statement's catch block is checked for a match.

I think I understood it correctly and wrote this test code as follows:

```
try {

    try {
        throw "error";
    }

} catch( e ) {

    console.log( e );

}
```

But got this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try`

I know it clearly says that I am missing a catch or finally but the JavaScript documentation says my code should be valid or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You do realize that a `try {}` block without either a `catch` of a `finally` wouldn't actually accomplish anything even if it was allowed since the only reason to put something in a `try` block is so you can handle an exception.  It makes sense this is an error.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just testing it out and thought I was misunderstanding the docs so I consulted SO for an explanation an the link to this helped out more than the MDN guide: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.14

Comment: @jfriend00 You can have write `try { /* something */} finally {}` and it would run. I also think that this would change the behavior of error handling. So this is more like javascript trying to teach programmers how to write code - how does that make sense?

Comment: @Rolf - Since a `try` doesn't do anything without having a `catch` or `finally`, it makes sense that the language would prohibit just a `try` block all by itself.  Yes, you can put an empty `finally {}` if you really want to.  That at least meets the language syntax rules.

Comment: @jfriend00 You know you can write a line such as `42;`, it does nothing yet is valid JS. Anyway I can understand the process through which such a syntax would be mandatory.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The quoted text is quite misleading because it says "if an inner try..catch doesn't have a catch block" which doesn't make any sense. It should just be "if an inner `try` doesn't have...".

In JavaScript, you can't just have a `try` on its own; it *has* to have a `catch`, `finally`, or both. So the scenario that quote is referring so isa `try/catch` containing a **`try/finally`** (not another `try/catch`):

```
try {
    try {
        throw "error";
    }
    finally {
    }
} catch( e ) {
    console.log( e );
}
```

Comment: The spec says: "The try...catch statement consists of a try block, which contains one or more statements, and zero or more catch blocks", but where does it say anything about zero catch blocks ==> a `finally` block is required?

Comment: @BaseZen: In [§12.14](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.14), where it shows the valid list of `try` statements, which are "`try` *Block* *Catch*", "`try` *Block* *Finally*", and "`try` *Block* *Catch* *Finally*" (note the absense of simply "`try` *Block*").

Comment: I think somebody should fix the misleading documentation/guide.

Comment: @samyismyhero: MDN is collaboratively-edited by end users, and while usually very good, this means it's sometimes just plain wrong (sometimes in much worse ways than this slightly poor phrasing). (It also means *you* can fix it if you like, you just need a Mozilla account.)

Comment: You know it's funny I was reading documentation on the same MDN on a different subject and they were linking to SO as a form of guidance.

Answer (score 5):

It is specified here: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

> The try statement consists of a try block, which contains one or more
>   statements, **and at least one catch clause or a finally clause**, or
>   both. That is, there are three forms of the try statement:

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    try {
        throw "error1";
    } catch (e1){
      console.log(e1)
    }
    throw "error2";
} catch( e2 ) {
    console.log( e2 );
}

>>> error1
>>> error2
```

In other words, the inner try-catch does not get picked up by the outer try-catch.

However, if you forget the inner catch, and close the inner try-catch with a 'finally' instead, your statement is valid and the inner error is passed on to the outer try-catch. I struggle to see why one would every do that in reality unless it's by accident. If you try something, your intention is to catch the error case I think.

```
    try {
        try {
            throw "error1";
        } finally  {
          console.log('final stuff')
        }
        throw "error2";
    } catch( e2 ) {
        console.log( e2 );
    }

>>> final stuff
>>> error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the same [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#exception_handling_statements) you are referencing, it mentions this:

> If an inner `try` block does not have a corresponding `catch` block:
>
> 1. it must contain a `finally` block, and
> 2. the enclosing `try...catch` statement's catch block is checked for a match.

It seems to be that your code is missing a `finally` block since you chose to omit out the `catch` block.